# CORS problems no 'access control allow origin header' is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, cors

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
function fetch() {
              $http.get("http://www.myapifilms.com/imdb/top")
                .success(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  $scope.details = response;
                });
            };
```

The error i'm receiving is the following:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.myapifilms.com/imdb/top. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I've looked up quite a bit on this issue or CORS but still can't seem to realize what i have to add and in which file(s).

Comment: Use JSONP in this case.

Comment: I've tried the following: `function fetch() {
        $http.jsonp("http://www.myapifilms.com/imdb/top")
          .success(function(response) {
            $scope.details = response;

            console.log(response);
            console.log(details);
          });
      };`

But can't seem to get a console log going and details isn't getting filled up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that http://www.myapifilms.com does not allow "localhost" origin to access its data.

I could recommend two solutions:

- try using http-server by running `npm install -g http-server`
- download a chrome plugin(not recommended) but can be handy for testing  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: I'm planning on hosting the app on heroku as well, and also hosting the db on heroku if i can with keystoneJS. Would it accept those urls? Also, how to test it using the http-server? What do i add in my code then?

Comment: hosting your app on heroku might work as it will provide you with a URL . In the back the apifilms people have written a line saying that allow any connection from a "website URL" but not any origin.. its for security purposes i guess. http-server again depends on their permissions.. for testing just download the chrome plugin and you would be good to go

Comment: I've now worked with $http.jsonp() but i still can't seem to get it to work... if you're interested : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191130/http-jsonp-doesnt-load-in-data?noredirect=1#comment56130963_34191130 .

Answer (score 0):

For this request to succeed, the response from myapifilms.com would need the correct headers set. What you *should* do is route your request through a server of your own. However you could get around it for testing purposes with a [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

[Explained in detail here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: Mhm yes it's probably because it doesn't allow localhost to connect, would hosting my app on heroku make it work, since it won't be localhost anymore.

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

```
//make headers for service
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('appCurrentVersionNumber', AppConstant.APP_VERSION);
headers.append('WebServiceIdentifier', AppStorage.getItem('webserviceidentifier'));
this.headers = {headers}; this.http.post(API_URL + 'checkInVan', JSON.stringify(userData), this.headers).map(res => res.json());
```